# IBM Data Server licence for JDBC and SQLJ is invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, db2

Im trying to connect to an IBM DB2 in AS400 using jdbc and ibm DB2 jcc driver.
credentials are valid. the problem is, when i try to connect to the client db2, it tells me that my db2 connect licence is invalid. even though i tied to connect with the same driver to another IBM DB2 in a free ibm cloud service, and it works without the licence.

is there another way to connect to IBM DB2 without DB2 connect ? or there is no other way than buying the licence ?

The error :

[image]

My application.properties

[image]

Comment: This is a FAQ.  When using an IBM-supplied driver to connect to AS/400 ( i series), then either pay (directly or indirectly) for a Db2-connect license, or alternatively use the  jt400 driver (free ).   If your company already has a Db2-connect gateway product installed ($$), then you can connect indirectly via the gateway.

Comment: Ok I'll try it out, thank you.

Comment: When i try to connect using the jt400 driver it throws a connect timed out Exception, even  with the correct credentials tested with db2 connect.

Comment: That is a different problem, unrelated to licensing, unrelated to your original question. Either your host/port are incorrect, or a firewall blocks the path, or you've made some other error with configuration. Study the jt400 docs carefully.

Comment: Open a new question, show your new code, and the __full__ details of the new exception, tag it db2-400 and db2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IBM supplied drivers, access to i-series (AS/400) is non free.

You can use the jt400 driver if you want "free" access.

Otherwise you must either provide a Db2-connect licence on the workstation running the jdbc connection and thus connect directly to AS/400 (i-series), or if your company has already deployed a Db2-connect gateway then you can connect **indirectly** via that gateway and in this case no workstation-side license is required (because the costs are included in the separate Db2-connect gateway license).